# Extracting a Function from Inside an Integral

Tags: integration, convolution, signal-processing, deconvolution

I have an imaging system that produces a signal in a pixel, in part, by responding to incident radiance $L(\lambda)$ that passes through a filter with transmission $T(\lambda)$. Lumping all the other parameters under a generic constant I can write the signal:
$S = k\cdot\int L(\lambda)\ast T(\lambda)d\lambda\,$.
I'm trying to find a way to determine, or even estimate $L(\lambda)$. The system is such that I know $S, k$, and $T(\lambda)$. Is there a way to recover the incident radiance? Note, I am not necessarily looking for a closed form solution, approximation is fine.

Comment: I don't know what tags (signal theory?) would help you find your audience, but it seems like [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) is either a key word or might lead you towards the right things.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: This isn't going to happen. The possible $L$ form an infinite-dimensional vector space, and you have a single value to pick it from. It doesn't help that you know $T$. That just moves things around. You can increase $L$ in one region and decrease it in another to get the same value $S$. Because of that, this isn't enough information to provide even a single value of $L(\lambda)$.

Comment: That sounds about right. Thanks for explaining why. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll close this question.

Thanks much Paul!